# Selecting multiple elements with same classname using CSS

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

So i have a list of questions on the home page like this:

```
<div id="question-summary-36771853" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772065" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772003" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772259" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772257" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772256" class="question-summary narrow">
<div id="question-summary-36772253" class="question-summary narrow">
```

now the id changes everytime the page is refreshed. I want to know how can i use CSS selector to capture just the first 5 questions.

Comment: You can't in CSS...you'd need javascript or some other selection method

Answer (score 1):

You can partially match the `id` using the "starts-with" or "contains" notation:

```
div[id^="question-summary-"]
```

Or, you can check the class instead of id:

```
div.question-summary
```

As for limiting it to 5 first elements only, you can use the "findElements" method of your selenium language bindings and slice the result. Example in Python:

```
questions = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[id^="question-summary-"]')
first_5_questions = questions[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll like a CSS only based way to do it, you could use `:nth-child` pseudo-selector, to select only the first 5 elements. It's a little bit manual, but can be achieved with CSS like this:

```
.question-summary:nth-child(1),
.question-summary:nth-child(2),
.question-summary:nth-child(3),
.question-summary:nth-child(4),
.question-summary:nth-child(5) {
   /* your style goes here */
}
```